# How to create a simple, dynamic list within the cells of a column

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Here's the situation: I have a spreadsheet with two columns, A and B. The cells of each column use Excel's Data Validation to have a drop down list within them.

A's cells have a drop down list with values [0, 1, 2, 3].
B's cells have a drop down list with values [True, False].

I would like to condition the values of the list within the cells of the B column based upon the selected value of the cell in the A column of the same row.

Here's precisely what I'd like to achieve: if a cell in A has a value 0 or 1, then the drop down list of the cell in B of the same row will only have one value, [True]. Otherwise, the cell in B of the same row has [True, False]. That is all.

I'm a programmer by profession but I have been humbled by VBA. I would be most grateful for any solution, whether it needs to use VBA or not. Thank you.

Comment: [Dependent Drop Down Lists](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
H1:  TRUE
H2:  FALSE
```

Validation formula in B1:

```
=OFFSET($H$1,0,0,IF($A1<2,1,2))
```

or, for a non-volatile formula:

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$2,IF($A1<2,1,0))
```

Copy/ paste special validation as far down as needed in column B

Comment: Thank you. What I'm gathering from these responses and what I've been searching online is that to achieve my goal I will have to modify some cells in my spreadsheet for the sole purpose of storing TRUE and FALSE. Currently this is not how the drop down lists are being populated, instead they simply have the Source text field in the Data Validation dialog to say True, False. This creates the list without having to add True or False to any cell in the spreadsheet.

I would prefer to maintain this behavior because this excel sheet will be sent to users of an application. But there is no way?

Comment: @gfitz It's probably the simplest method. You can put your list on a hidden, proyected sheet for distribution. You could also use VBA and event-triggered macros to dynamically change the list.